# How do I get the total number of results returned from a subquery in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the total number of results returned from a subquery. This is my query:

```
select 
    count(r.reason_id) as num,
    cast (count(r.reason_id) as float) / (select count(*) as total from r) * 100.0 as pct
from (
    select
        case
            when rarreason != 0 then rarreason
            else rejectreason end as reason_id
    from 
        workorderlines 
    where
        (rarreason != 0 or rejectreason != 0)
    ) as r

group by
    r.reason_id
```

However, when I try and execute this, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "r" does not exist
LINE 3: ...on_id) as float) / (select count(*) as total from r) * 100.0...
                                                             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "r" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 112
```

How do I do this? I am using Postgresql 9.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't check your logic but you can rearrange it like this:

```
with r as (
    select
        case
            when rarreason != 0 then rarreason
            else rejectreason end as reason_id
    from 
        workorderlines 
    where
        (rarreason != 0 or rejectreason != 0)
)
select 
    count(r.reason_id) as num,
    cast (count(r.reason_id) as float) / (select count(*) as total from r) * 100.0 as pct
from r
group by r.reason_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select 
    count(r.reason_id) as num,
    cast (count(r.reason_id) as float) / max(r.count_all) * 100.0 as pct
from (
    select
        case
            when rarreason != 0 then rarreason
            else rejectreason end as reason_id,
        count(*) over () as count_all
    from 
        workorderlines 
    where
        (rarreason != 0 or rejectreason != 0)
    ) as r

group by
    r.reason_id
```

Comment: This worked as well as the other one, thank you! I have a question though, what exactly does `count(*) over () count_all` do?

Comment: @DiZou: `count(*) over ()` is an example of using `count(*)` as a window function - see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html . `count_all` is a column alias - the `as` is optional.